# Invoke Java Method When Button Is Clicked

Tags: java, jsp

I have an old JSP application for which I cannot use Jquery or Ajax.

I have the following code snippet

```
function func(val){
if(val=="true"){
<%
myBean.myMethod("ABC","DET",0);
%>
 myfrm.submit(); 
 }
 }
```

and I am calling this from a button's onClick event.

What I would like to do is invoke my Java method only when button is clicked. If page is refreshed java method should not be invoked.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Java scriptlets are executed server-side. By the time your page reaches the user they are gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. The java code is only executed when you refresh/load the page. Once the page is rendered, only client-side code can be executed.

Answer (score 1):

You could have the button post to x.jsp and then do a redirect y.jsp

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have called your method within the jsp lifecycle.
As the jsp is parsed your method will be executed.

The functionallity you want you will  most likely have to create an event.

```
<input type="hidden" value="" id="executeThis" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();"/>

<button id="doWork" type="button" onclick="execTheClick('executeThis', 'methodName');"/>


function execTheClick(linkId, methodName)
{
    var fireOnThis = document.getElementById(linkId);
    fireOnThis.value = methodName;
    if (document.createEvent)
    {
        var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        evObj.initEvent( 'click', true, false );
        fireOnThis.dispatchEvent(evObj);
    }
    else if (document.createEventObject)
    {
        var evObj = document.createEventObject();        
        fireOnThis.fireEvent('onclick',evObj);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: So where do I call java method?